# PHP Download Problem: Not Successful w/ Slow Connection Speeds

Tags: php, download

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, and have yet to find a solution that fixes the problem I'm having.

**What I'm Trying To Do:**

I'm attempting to use PHP to download PDFs, and the code works very well for files that can download within about a minute and a half.  On my home wifi, I'm able to download a 159MB file within 10 seconds, and it works every time.  But when I limit the internet speed to "Fast 3G" (around 170KB/s, in order to simulate slower office speeds), the download fails.  And nearly every time, it does so exactly 3 minutes and 24 seconds into the download process, but occasionally it is a lower time of 1 minute and 57 seconds.

**What I've Tried:**

I've tweaked the php.ini file (setting max_execution_time = 0, and memory_limit at higher intervals than the originally configured 128M)

I've tried other download methods that seem to "chunk" the larger PDFs.  This has been mostly unsuccessful.  In one instance the download would complete, but there would be an error when trying to open the PDF.  According to the poster of this solution, it was only a valid solution for UTF-8 encoded files, and I found the one's I'm dealing with to be UTF-16.  (I believe it was some kind of incompatibility with the print() function.

I've made sure the file can download if using a direct link in the URL.  It has no problems this way, but it was only done for testing, and cannot be a permanent solution because the PDFs I'm dealing with contain sensitive information.  So based off of this result, I was at least able to narrow down the problem to be PHP related and not IIS.

Here's the current code I'm using

```php
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header("Content-Type: application/download");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            //$file is a full path to the PDF

            while(ob_get_level()) {
                ob_end_clean();
            }
            readfile($file); 
            flush();

        exit;

        /*I realize it may be off, but it is at least working for quicker load 
        times as it currently is, so I'm leaving it alone for now*/
```

I tried to include any information that seemed relevant, but if any additional information would be useful please let me know!  I will also be sure to include the current code that is handling the download process that I mentioned at the top of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```php
readfile($file); 
flush();
```

I would try

```php
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
while (!feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 8192);
    flush();
}
fclose($handle);
```

you may need to adjust the above to handle proper encoding, but that will depend on your environment

Comment: I appreciate the response!  I tried this, and I was still left with the same problem.  I've been trying to figure out why, but I'm still pretty stuck on it.  When you say "adjust the above to handle proper encoding", could you clarify what you mean by this please?  I don't think I'm understanding well enough to make progress as of right now.  Thank you!

Comment: So I’ve spent many more hours on this and still ave not figured out what is wrong.  Either the PDF download stops partway through and is unsuccessful(usually ended at the same download progress each time), or the file downloads completely, but is then corrupted and unable to be opened.  Any ideas as to why this might be? Thanks!